# fragments with intentfilter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an Android application.I have to convert one activity to fragment. But the activity is registered in manifest file with some intent-filters. How can I convert this activity to fragment with intent filter.Please help me friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fragment needs to be contained within an Activity, so you can't place an intent filter on the fragment itself. You can however place the needed intent filters on the Activity containing the fragment.

Comment: can i add <action android:name="com.blisd.blisdapp.scanner.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  this for parent activity?

Comment: yes. If it works for any activity it will work for the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

At last i found answer for my doupt. The solution is register intent-filter with parent fragmentActivity.

Comment: Why did you make a new answer that you marked as accepted insted of just marking my answer as accepted?